Unable to create Rust flamegraphs using Criteriion and Pprof on Mac
I am trying to set up criterion and pprof on a Rust library to generate flamegraphs. I was mainly following this guide https://www.jibbow.com/posts/criterion-flamegraphs/
I followed this example on pprof github https://github.com/tikv/pprof-rs/blob/v0.4.2/examples/criterion.rs
The following is what my cargo.toml looks like
[profile.profiling]
inherits = "release"
name = "my_benchmark"

[dev-dependencies]
criterion = "0.5"
pprof = { version = "0.13", features = ["flamegraph", "criterion"] }

[[bench]]
name = "my_benchmark"
harness = false

benches/my_benchmark.rs
extern crate operation_tree;
use criterion::{criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};
use pprof::{
    criterion::{Output, PProfProfiler},
    flamegraph::Options,
};
use rand::Rng;
fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let x: Vec<f64> = (0..1000).map(|_x| rng.gen_range(0.0..10.0)).collect();
    c.bench_function("operation_tree", |b| b.iter(|| operation_tree::add_two(&x)));
}

criterion_group! {
    name = benches;
    config = Criterion::default().with_profiler(PProfProfiler::new(100,Output::Flamegraph(Some(Options::default()))));
    targets = criterion_benchmark
}
criterion_main!(benches);


src/lib.rs
pub fn add_two(x: &[f64]) -> Vec<f64> {
    let mut y = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..x.len() {
        y.push(x[i] * 2.0);
    }
    y
}


I ran cargo bench --bench my_benchmark, but no file called flamegraph could be found in the target/criterion folder or its subfolders

So what code did you run? It's not quite clear since you reference 2 different guides. Your post should be self contained anyways so please add a [mre] to your question.

@cafce25 I added the code
